# What is the Essential Reason that allows a PTAS for the EUCLIDEAN TSP?

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, computational-complexity

Questions:

- Is there some understanding of the reason, why the euclidean TSP allows a PTAS, whereas the metric TSP in general does not and, is the PTAS stable under sufficiently small perturbation of the edge weights of an euclidean TSP?
- If sufficiently small perturbations of the edge weights do not harm a PTAS, the PTAS can't be tied to euclidicity of the instance and there should be more general conditions for metric TSPs that allow a PTAS; are such conditions known or being investigated?

Comment: What's a TSP and a PTAS?

Comment: @LeeMosher I didn't explain TSP and PTAS because I do not see the danger of confusing interpreting the abreviation as anything else but Traveling Salesman Problem and Polynomial Time Approximation Scheme.

Comment: @Manfred: That's a very incorrect assumption. Someone working in your research area might immediately know what you mean by TSP and PTAS, but the majority of the people on MO is *not* working in your research area...

Comment: @TomDeMedts I have the same problem with anything that relates to categories or sheaves and a lot of other things, e.g. the ABC conjecture. My usual reaction is to feed my favorite search engine with the things I don't know and, most of the time I find some papers or wiki articles that provide me with sufficient background information.

Comment: *If sufficiently small perturbations of the edge weights do not harm a PTAS, the PTAS can't be tied to euclidicity of the instance* -- I don't see why that follows....

Comment: The abstract of Arora's original paper says "All our algorithms also work, with almost no modiﬁcation, when distance is measured using
any geometric norm (such as $\ell_p$ for $p \geq 1$ or other Minkowski norms)." http://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs468-06-winter/Papers/arora-tsp.pdf

Comment: @usul because small perturbations of the edge weights can render the instance to be not euclidean anymore (add for example $\epsilon$ of sufficiently small magnitude to a single edge) and then the existence of a PTAS can't depend on euclidicity itself; it could however be, that a certain proximity to an euclidean TSP could be the condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the key ingredients in Arora's proof is the Patching Lemma, which allows you to reduce the number of crossings between subregions while expanding the length of a tour by a controlled amount.  An analogue of the Patching Lemma can be proved for more general normed spaces, but not for general metric spaces.

Note, however, that although the Patching Lemma is needed if you want to apply Arora's method "out of the box", Arora himself suggests that the Patching Lemma may not be any kind of intrinsic barrier.  Ultimately, there may be no more satisfying "reason" why the general metric TSP does not admit a PTAS beyond the PCP theorem.

Comment: And note that Mitchell independently discovered (about the same time) a PTAS for TSP, based on his *guillotine subdivisions*: "Guillotine Subdivisions Approximate Polygonal Subdivisions: A Simple Polynomial-Time Approximation Scheme for Geometric TSP, k-MST, and Related Problems." I cannot myself summarize to what extent his algorithm relies on the Euclidean metric.

Comment: @Manfred Weis: I should have mentioned this earlier, but you might get a more detailed answer if you post at cstheory.stackexchange.com.